# different fill and border using turtle

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

I have a function which makes a window:

```
import turtle
t=turtle.Pen()       

def drawindow(dis):
    t.down()
    t.seth(0)
    drawshape(4, 15)
    t.up()
    t.fd(7.5)
    t.seth(90)
    t.down()
    t.fd(15)
    t.up()
    t.seth(180)
    t.fd(7.5)
    t.seth(270)
    t.fd(7.5)
    t.seth(0)
    t.down()
    t.fd(15)
    t.end_fill()
```

I want the pen colour to be black, but the fill to be another colour. I have defined a function `drawhouse()` which includes this function, and before this, the pen colour is set to black, and the fill begins. I tried doing `t.begin_fill('blue')`, but this does not work. please help.

`drawshape(x, y)` draws a polygon with  x sides, each side y long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

before you begin drawing, try calling

```
t.color('black', 'blue')
```

This sets the fill colour to blue and the line colour to black.

Alternatively, you can call

```
t.pencolor('black')
t.fillcolor('blue')
```

Individually if you would prefer. Check out the documentation at http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/turtle.html#turtle.color

Comment: thankyou very much, that works fine.
a very simple to understand answer as well- thanks

Comment: Worth noting the position of the 'fill' color changes with the number of parameters. For example, `t.color('black')` fills black, while `t.color('black', 'blue')` fills blue with a black outline.